Can you put power PVCs on exterior wall or inside concrete only?
In original houses. All the PVC pipes for electrical wires are inside walls encased in concrete or under the soil. Is it a rule in the American electrical code that all such must be inside concrete or under soil? What if you want to make a new pipe for new wires and you can't pull out the one old under soil? Can you put the the PVC pipes and electrical wires inside them on walls and not within the concrete?

Conduit(pipes) can be used anywhere.  There are certain types required for protection in certain areas that are stronger.  PVC on outside walls need to have UV protection(most electrical PVC does).

Is it also possible not to use any conduit at all in small areas where you cant put conduit bec of lack of space?

If using conduit, most people use single wires and not cables.  Single wires must be in conduit all the way.

Do you consider AWG#1 stranded with black and red wires stranded as single wires or cables? Btw can rats chew THHN insulation?

Cables are red, black, white, or other colours of wires combined in a covering together.  Stranded or solid does not matter.  Rats can chew most stuff, except metal/concrete.

There are multiple types of plastic conduit, including PVC, and multiple types of metal conduit. Some of each type (e.g., PVC schedule 80) can be used where subject to damage and some (e.g., PVC schedule 40) can only be used where not subject to damage. Typically this means exposed walls (i.e., not behind drywall or paneling or whatever) up to 8' (exact height seems to vary depending on who/where you ask). Which means that conduit inside walls, as well as conduit that is underground or in concrete, can be the cheaper, thinner, types (but there are a bunch of detailed rules to follow) and exposed above ground but below ceiling height requires the more expensive thicker types.
Keep in mind a few additional key pieces:

In most areas, except primarily for Chicago, New York City and some other large cities, single-family homes and, typically, townhouses or similar small groups of homes can use non-metallic (NM) cable, commonly referred to by the trade name Romex. NM cable has an outer sheath which does not protect from serious damage, so it still needs protection in the same areas where you need to use better conduit when running individual wires, but for running cable overhead and in walls that will be covered it is a lot easier than running conduit + wires.
In most areas you can't use NM cable in large multi-family or commercial buildings. There you must use wires in conduit.
Cables can be run in conduit to provide protection. But  you generally want to do that only for short runs - e.g., down an open wall from the ceiling to a junction box. If you have a long run then you are much better off running individual wires in conduit rather than cables in conduit.
Individual wires are not normally allowed to be exposed even for a few inches! For example, if you are running wires between a main panel and a subpanel a foot away, you install conduit between the two panels and run the wires inside the conduit.
Certain types of metal conduit (basically the heavier-duty ones) also provide ground so that you don't need to run a ground wire.
If you abandon old cable or wires, you should remove them if practical. At a minimum, disconnect them from any equipment, circuit breakers, etc. Ideally, unless you think there is a reasonable chance of future use, cut them so that there is no exposed wire in the box on either end.
Reusing conduit should be easy. But sometimes it is not possible - e.g., the old conduit was sized just large enough to carry wires for 100A service and you are upgrading to 200A service. And sometimes there is damage to the conduit such that it is no longer possible to properly run wires through it.


Why cant single wires not allowed to be exposed even for few inches? Is it just to avoid rats chewing the insulation? But cant the rat also chew the pvc pipe itself?

As I understand it, the rules - as with many safety-related rules - are a balance. In a perfect world, perhaps rigid metal conduit (the really heavy-duty stuff) would be used for everything whether cables or wires or even low-voltage (alarms, computer networks, etc.). And in fact I suspect that in nuclear power plants and submarines and similar dangerous environments they do go to those types of extremes. But in ordinary buildings basically there is a hierarchy - heavy metal or heavy plastic (PVC 80) around things that need the most protection, lighter metal or plastic or "just cables" for

things that need less protection. But wires by themselves only when inside boxes (junction boxes, breaker panels, etc.). Could a beaver or some other animal with big teeth get through PVC 80? Probably. Rigid metal conduit? Probably not. But indoors hopefully we're just talking rats and mice (I've seen enough of them...) and PVC 40 is certainly enough and if things are under reasonable control even ordinary cables are good enough. But individual wires? Just too easy to have a problem.
